# How to add maven modules to IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ cannot find the classes in a Maven module, even if I add the jar dependency into pom.xml.

I created a Maven module: test-intellij . And then I created a class `TestApp` and made it implements `ApplicationContextAware` as below:

```
public class TestApp implements  ApplicationContextAware{
}
```

IntelliJ told me: "can not find class ApplicationContextAware". 
So I pressed "alt + enter", then from the popup tips I chose "Add maven dependency".

After this operation, the dependency below was added into pom.xml successfully:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But when I try to import the ApplicationContextAware class , IntelliJ still cannot find the ApplicationContextAware class to import.

Could anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: try and keep your questions to the point, and not so chit chatty / email like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to **Reimport** the Maven project using the corresponding button in IntelliJ IDEA `Maven Projects` tool window. Wait until the dependency is downloaded and indexing is complete. `File` | `Invalidate Caches` may also help.

Also check that you are using the latest IDEA version (12.0.2 at the moment). You should be able to browse inside the downloaded dependency jar in the `Project View`, `External Libraries` node.

Comment: thanks CrazyCoder , i finally solve this issue according to your suggestion . and i also check the "auto import maven project" option in the maven setting panel.